# Block Top Menu - Heading/Categories

Tags: menu, block, prestashop-1.6

How can I insert the heading of the categories in Prestashop 1.6 using block top menu. At present, only sub-categories are shown. Please help. 
Refer to the below link for reference:
http://bigbasket.com/ 
Could you see that on hovering through categories, Category heading is displayed. I want to know how to modify topblockmenu in prestashop 1.6 to reciprocate the same.

Comment: Hi is it possible for you to share a screen shot what result you want and what is currently happening on your site just to understand bit more? Thanks

Comment: Please refer the site above.